# Uncaught Twilio.Exception: Run Twilio.Device.setup()

Tags: twilio

I keep getting

```
Uncaught Twilio.Exception: Run Twilio.Device.setup()
```

when starting a call after the page posts back.

The problem is not consistent and after refreshing the page several times it goes away and i can make outbound calls again. But it happens at least once after a post back.

any ideas..?

Comment: Might be a race condition between calling `Device.setup()` and `Device.ready`? you can't call the second without calling the first.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to be clear, are you using the Twilio Client JavaScript SDK?

If that is indeed the case, can you try hitting http://clientsupport.twilio.com/ to make sure that your browser will support Twilio Client.  If everything lights up green there, I'd suggest taking the output from the browser check site and opening a case with our awesome customer support team.  You can simply send and email to help@twilio.com

Hope that helps.